# Formulating H0 and H1 based on a sentence

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Let $X_1,..,X_n$ be a random sample from a $\mathcal{N}(\theta, 1)$.
Suppose that we want to test $\theta \leq 0.0$.

Should I say

```
H0: theta <= 0.0
H1: theta > 0.0
```

or

```
H0: theta > 0.0
H1: theta <= 0.0
```

What's the convention? Is it just a convention, or does it matter more than the convention?

Comment: Your null is the opposite of what you wish to test, i.e. "suppose that this is not true, can I find evidence to the contrary?".

Comment: The technical expressions like $H_0:\theta\le 0$ are perfectly clear, but the English phrase "test $\theta\le 0.0$" is ambiguous: what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: @whuber I meant: I want to find out if theta is below 0.0

Comment: Then it's important to state that clearly and unambiguously, because in science (at least) when you want to find out something, *you set out to falsify it.*  In this case, you would seek evidence that might possibly contradict what you want to show.

Comment: @whuber I'm not 100% sure I understand what you meant. Would you mind clarifying it? Sorry.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is to note that the hypothesis testing framework does **not** allow to accept the null hypothesis.

Comment: Therefore, if I'm "trying" to prove theta <= 0; I should use the second H0/H1 formalism?

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows Yes, the second one.  As some say, the null hypothesis is made to be rejected in favor of the alternative.

Comment: How do you calculate the p-value under the second null? Which value of $\theta$ do you use.

Comment: @dimitriy well in both scenarios, I don't know what value of $\theta$ to use?

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows Typically one would use the edge of the region demarcated under the null to get the p-value. Here the region lacks that boundary in (2), since for any value less than zero, I can find one closer to zero.

Comment: So for scenario one, I would assume theta = 0 to get the p-value?

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows Yup, so the first pair in your question.